# How can we hide the Sensitive Data in xCode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift3

I am new to iOS Development and have no much idea about secure iOS coding and my requirement is to hide API & Secrete Key in my xCode project. Is there any secure technique or location in xCode where I can keep the data so the it would not be accessed by malicious user.

Comment: There is no secure location to save API and Secret Key.

Answer (score 0):

This is really great question and a problem that needs more recognition.

AFAIK there is no out of the box solution provided within Xcode. I often use the plugin for `cocoapods` [here](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-keys). You will need to specify which keys you're using and then after hitting `pod install` for the first time you'll be prompted to specify the values which are then stored securely in your keychain. This plugin automatically generates an interface to access all your keys in code.

Notice that it stores all your keys locally so if another developer clones your repo and hits `pod install` he will be prompted to provide the keys again. You can create a shared vault in some password managing service like `1 Password` and add all your keys to share it with your team.

It also works using CI systems, where instead of keychain the env variables are being checked for the given key presence.

The con here is that it forces you to use `cocoapods` at least for installing the plugin, even though you might prefer some other dependency manager.